# Python, How to pass loop index name as a os.system command for an output

Tags: python, export-to-csv

```
def node_runlist():
 csvfile = open("/tmp/noderunlist.csv", "a")
 writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
 writer.writerow(['NodeName','Environment','IP','Roles','Recipes','Platform'])
 report = os.system("knife node list >> /tmp/node.txt")
 with open('/tmp/node.txt', 'r') as node_file:
 for node_name in node_file:
    print(node_name)
    writer.writerow([
        str(node_name),
        str(os.system("knife node show %node_name | grep Environment | awk 
          '{print $2}' ")),
        str(os.system("knife node show %node_name | grep IP | awk '{print 
           $2}' ")),
        str(os.system("knife node show %node_name | grep Run | awk '{print 
           $3}' ")),
        str(os.system("knife node show %node_name | grep Recipes | awk 
          '{print $2}' "))
     ])
```

How to pass loop index name as a os.system command for an output, below is the error:

> node_name
>
> sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('
>   sh: -c: line 0: `knife node show %(node_name)s | grep Environment | awk '{print $2}' '
>   sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('
>   sh: -c: line 0: `knife node show %(node_name)s | grep IP | awk '{print $2}' '
>   sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('
>   sh: -c: line 0: `knife node show %(node_name)s | grep Run | awk '{print $3}' '
>   sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('
>   sh: -c: line 0: `knife node show %(node_name)s | grep Recipes | awk '{print $2}' '

Comment: https://realpython.com/python-string-formatting/

Comment: loop index is confusing. You may want to use `enumerate` instead. http://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/enumerate.html

Comment: The return value of `os.system()` is the exit code of the command; its output goes directly to your terminal, bypassing Python completely.  You will need to use one of the various methods in the `subprocess` module to actually get the output text.

Comment: Thank you. I will implement the string format and Sub-process method.